# What does the phrase "infinite order" mean?

Tags: graph-theory

I am student studying ad-hoc network. I cannot understand the last sentence in the following paragraph. What does it mean "*infinite-order*" component? Please let me know the concept of that word.

> In the theory of continuum percolation, nodes are assumed to be distributed with Poisson density $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and two nodes are connected to each other if the distance between them is at most $r$. It has been proven that, for each $\lambda\gt0$, there exists at most one infinite-order component with high probability.

Actually, I've never studied point Poisson process (PPP), but I could read some journals from only knowing the fact that it is the process that distributes node in a certain space with density. Thus, rigid explanations are surely very developmental and important. However, I hope to know rough concept of the word "*infinite-order*".

Comment: I would guess it means "containing infinitely many nodes".

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, just that? Is there any implicit meaning?? Thank you :) very much.

Comment: @Danny_Kim No, this is a classic result in percolation theory, the emergence of a single large connected component (with all other components in the random graph being finite in size).  It's not intuitively obvious that there shouldn't be two (or even infinitely many) large components, and this is what the use of "infinite-order" is drawing attention to here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, the [order of a graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphOrder.html) is typically just the number of nodes in that graph. So an infinite-order component is a connected component of the graph with infinitely many nodes. If the author meant something else by this phrase, we would have to have the context of the paragraph to be able to say anything more.